# How to evaluate why a method returns what it returns

Tags: c#

What strategy do you use to give to the user the reason why a certain method "failed"

Exemple:

```
public List<Balance> GetBalanceFinale(Periode periode)
    {
        if (periode == null || periode.DateStart >= DateTime.Now || isBalanceFinished(periode.PeriodeID))
            return null;

        //My other code...
     }
```

I want to tell the user which of the steps went wrong. I don't want to use a messagebox in such class. I can't return the description of the failure because I already return something.

What do you usally do? Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you don't want to throw an exception otherwise you would've already done that. Something like an alert / warning without stopping execution of the program. In that case, you can still use an exception, just don't throw it, instead pass it as an out parameter or put it somewhere where the user can access it if desired. If that seems over the top then just use a message instead.

Also framing it as a 'Try' method might be a good idea. It makes it very clear that the method is prone to failure under certain conditions.

These are all different options:

```
public bool TryGetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, out List<Balance> list, out string msg)
{
    // return false if anything is wrong, and have an out parameter for the result & msg
}

public bool TryGetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, out List<Balance> list, out Exception ex)
{
    // return false if anything is wrong, and have an out parameter for the exception
}
```

These first two above are my two preferred approaches. The following are possibilities as well, however they are somewhat non-standard:

```
public Tuple<string, bool> TryGetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, out List<Balance> list)
{
    // return false if anything is wrong, and include message in the returned Tuple
}


// an anonymous type approach
public object TryGetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, out List<Balance> list)
{
    return new {
       Successful = false,
       Message = // reason why here
    };
}

// a functional approach
public List<Balance> list GetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, Action<String> messageAct)
{
   // when something is wrong, do:
   messageAct("Something went wrong..."); 
}
```

I think the 'Try' strategy makes the most sense when you consider how it will be used:

```
string message;
List<Balance> result;

if (!TryGetBalanceFinale(periode, out result, out message))
{
    // examine the msg because you know the method failed
    Console.WriteLine(message); 
}
else
{
    // you know the method succeeded, so use the result
    Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + result.ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: Although I never particularly liked 'out' parameters, I think this solution is pretty neat!

Comment: The anonymous type approach strikes me as kind of horrifying.  I'd rather either use an actual type or a `Tuple`.  The idea of passing in an `Action` for how to handle errors is a bit odd, but highly effective under some situations.  In many cases, one can go a step further than that and just wrap the whole thing in a class.  If you do that, you would make failure into an event.

Answer (score 7):

You can throw an exception with a descriptive message.

Comment: aren't exceptions an unnecessary performance hit in this scenario?

Comment: Not a descriptive message, you might need multi-language support.  Throw a custom exception and set enums.  You can catch and parse this at your GUI level.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive, the question should be is the argument exceptional. If it is, treat it as such. An `ArgumentException` is perfectly reasonable in instances similar to the question.

Comment: It would be advisable that instead of throwing an exception at `GetBalanceFinale` to not allow `Periode` to be in an invalid state, and to throw an `Exception` when attempting to set `Periode` to an invalid state.  `GetBalanceFinale` should definitely throw `ArgumentNullException` if periode is null.

Answer (score 5):

Consider throwing exceptions instead of returning null.

In this case you will be able to provide descriptive information with each exception, which later can be properly handled and presented to the caller.

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 2):

I like to wrap my results in a `ResultState<T>` object (usually for Json or Xml serialization).  Might be helpful if you are building a framework for someone else to consume as each result can be handled the same way by the consumer.

```
public class ResultState<T>
{
  public T ResultValue { get; set; }
  public Exception ExceptionThrown { get; set; }
  public bool IsValid { get; set; }
  public string FriendlySummary  { get; set; }
  // whatever else properties you think are needed
}

public interface IResultState<T>
{
  public T ResultValue { get; }
  public Exception ExceptionThrown { get; }
  public bool IsValid { get; }
  public string FriendlySummary  { get; }
  // whatever else properties you think are needed
}

public IResultState<List<Balance>> GetBalanceFinale(Periode periode)
{
  ResultState<List<Balance>> result = new ResultState<List<Balance>>();
  try
  {
    if (periode == null 
        || periode.DateStart >= DateTime.Now 
        || isBalanceFinished(periode.PeriodeID))
    {
      result.IsValid = false;
      result.FriendlySummary = "Periode is in an invalid state.";
    }

    //My other code...

    result.ResultValue = new List<Balance>();
    result.ResultValue.Add(...);

  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    result.IsValid = false;
    result.Exception = ex;
    // Ambigious is bad.. so for bad example..
    result.FriendlySummary = "An unknown exception happened.";    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **re-factor** your code first. before calling `GetBalanceFinale` you can validate it and  show proper message if validation failed. if validation pass you can call `GetBalanceFinale` method.

Sometimes you may not able to do all the validation before calling the method. in that case you can throw exception with proper message or use out parameters.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that has worked for me in the past is the [Notification](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Notification.html) pattern.

This is a way of getting information out of your domain layer and up into the presentation. For example, create something like this:

```
public class Notification
{
  public List<Message> Messages;
  public bool HasMessages;
  // etc
}
```

and use an instance of it as a property on your domain.

You can then do something like this:

```
myDomain.GetBalanceFinale(periode);
if(myDomain.Notification.HasMessages)
  // get the messages and do something with them
```

Answer (score 1):

If I need to return a value and a message, I just use an out parameter.

```
public List<Balance> GetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, out string errorMessage)
{
    if (periode == null) 
    {
       errorMessage = "Periode is null";
       return null;
    }

    // Other checks
 }
```

Then just call it like

```
string errorMessage;
var value = GetBalanceFinale(periode, out errorMessage);
if(value == null)
   // Do whatever with errorMessage
```

Comment: In my opinion it makes much more sense for the List to be the out parameter. That is a standard practice, like all the 'TryParse' methods etc. in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose your logic into 3 separate tests, and then define an 'out' argument to return the "reason"

```
public List<Balance> GetBalanceFinale(Periode periode, out string reasonFailed)
{
    reasonFailed = false;
    if (periode == null)
    {  
       reasonFailed = "preiod is null";
       return null;
    }
    // etc.....
    //periode.DateStart >= DateTime.Now || isBalanceFinished(periode.PeriodeID))


    //My other code...
 }
```

Comment: Same as what Brandon said, I guess.  ...tie goes to the runner.

Comment: If you think your answer is the same as somebody else's answer, then remove yours (and usually upvote the other), particularly if the other was posted first.